# How to get GetLocalizedstring for announcement list

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, sharepoint-server, localization, sputility

I am trying to add xsltlistviewwebpart and it has to be from announcement list.

How to write this line?

```
string str = "$Resources:??";//How to get announcement list reference here?
public static string GetLocalizedStringforannouncement(SPWeb web)
{
return SPUtility.GetLocalizedString(str, "core", web.Language);
}
```

Please help.

Comment: Can anyone confirm is it $Resources:core,announceList??

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

**For title:**

```
string myListTitle = SPUtility.GetLocalizedString("$Resources:core,announceList;", "core", web.Language);
```

**For Description:**

```
string myListDesc = SPUtility.GetLocalizedString("$Resources:core,announceList_Desc;", "core", web.Language);
```